# Ignore whitespaces in scanf format

Tags: c, scanf

I read input using `scanf` in given format:

```
scanf("<%d;%d>%c", &lo, &hi, &op);
```

This accepts some string like `<1;10>k`. This works when I enter exactly in that syntax, but it doesn't work with whitespaces, so e.g. this won't work:

```
    <      1 ;
3 >      
 k
```

So how do I make `scanf` ignore these whitespaces?

Comment: Read the manual: [White space (such as blanks, tabs, or newlines) in the *format* string match any amount of white space, including none, in the input.](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/scanf/)

Comment: You just need `scanf(" <%d ;%d > %c", &lo, &hi, &op);` i think.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put spaces before the literal characters in the format string for [`scanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html).  You don't actually need spaces before most `%` conversion specifications (`%c`, `%n` and `%[…]` are the exceptions; they do *not* skip white space), but they may as well be there for symmetry (they do not harm).  Hence:

```
if (scanf(" < %d ; %d > %c", &lo, &hi, &op) == 3)
    …all OK — at least, three values were read OK…
```

If you were matching a `%` symbol in the input, you'd use `%%` in the format string; that'll [skip leading white space](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53200858/2410359) too.