# Should %% skip leading whitespace in scanf?

Tags: c, scanf, language-lawyer

According to the specification of `fscanf` in C17 7.21.6.2/8:

> Input white-space characters (as specified by the `isspace` function) are skipped, unless the specification includes a `[` , `c` , or `n` specifier

If the format string contains `%%`, then it is a specification with a `%` specifier. That isn't `[`, `c`, or `n`, so the standard appears to say that leading whitespace should be skipped here.

My question is: is this a correct interpretation, or is it a defect in the standard?

I tested two different implementations (mingw-w64 with MSVCRT stdio, and mingw-w64 with MinGW stdio). The former did not skip leading whitespace, the latter did.

Test code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a, r;

    // Should be 1 according to standard; would be 0 if %% does not skip whitespace
    r = sscanf("x %1", "x%% %d", &a);
    printf("%d\n", r);

    // Should always be 1
    r = sscanf("x%1", "x%% %d", &a);
    printf("%d\n", r);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should skip whitespace.

The specification has an example that says specifically that whitespace should be skipped:

> EXAMPLE 5 The call:
>
> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
> /* ... */
> int n, i;
> n = sscanf("foo %bar 42", "foo%%bar%d", &i);
> ```
>
> will assign to `n` the value `1` and to `i` the value `42` because input white-space characters are skipped for both
>   the `%` and `d` conversion specifiers.

Comment: Huh.  I'm surprised; I would have thought `%%` would be specified as  _not a conversion at all_, but rather, notation for the literal character `%`.  But [that's not how it's done](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.2).  (Probably because the original implementation of `scanf` was sloppy and everyone else had to copy that for backward compatibility's sake.)

Comment: I agree, I found it surprising as well. I would have been less surprised if they'd simply forgot to address it specifically, as the OP suspected.